Celery Task multiple submissions or duplications
I have a simple celery worker(redis and postgresql backend) that runs 3 periodic tasks [every 15 mins, every hour, every day].
For some reason that I haven't been able to deduce yet, my tasks are repeated i.e. the same task is being executed 6 times. (not sure if this number is significant)
I've tried multiple brokers, configs etc. The issue remains the same.
A snippet of my log file:
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,008: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[8efd7bde-46ae-4148-b967-604edf71a5ed] received
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,009: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[9e0a92f9-b025-4a08-8142-461a3c92658d] received
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,009: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[7eb05907-8a68-4a76-96d2-96c9c66edbf2] received
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,009: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[dd12c5ed-1698-4a2e-b993-fa77e87f814f] received
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,011: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[f76e83d9-dbc3-480c-963f-ca5adc0f8c5d] received
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,011: INFO/MainProcess] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[b5c8f174-a516-4f60-9bec-14c778cd328a] received

[2024-07-15 15:15:00,159: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[f76e83d9-dbc3-480c-963f-ca5adc0f8c5d] succeeded in 0.14488737506326288s: None
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,193: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[8efd7bde-46ae-4148-b967-604edf71a5ed] succeeded in 0.1789771249750629s: None
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,251: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[dd12c5ed-1698-4a2e-b993-fa77e87f814f] succeeded in 0.23766187496948987s: None
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,271: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[9e0a92f9-b025-4a08-8142-461a3c92658d] succeeded in 0.25732737500220537s: None
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,311: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[b5c8f174-a516-4f60-9bec-14c778cd328a] succeeded in 0.29686645802576095s: None
[2024-07-15 15:15:00,352: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes[7eb05907-8a68-4a76-96d2-96c9c66edbf2] succeeded in 0.3402104169363156s: None

As you can see, the same task is being acknowledged 6 different times all uniquely.
For additional context, these tasks run a series of SQL queries that refresh some materialized views. Due to the tasks being "duplicated" our db is under considerable unnecessary load and I'd like to correct that.
My celery initialization file
import logging
import os
import sys
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

load_dotenv("./.env")

# Set up the logging configuration programmatically
logger = logging.getLogger('celery')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Console handler
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

# Timed rotating file handler
file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/celery.log', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=15)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "enable_utc": True,
    "task_acks_late": True,
    "result_expires": 60*30,
    "celeryd_prefetch_multiplier": 2,
    "celery_queue_max_length": 1000,
    'broker_connection_retry_on_startup': False,
    'worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss': True,
}

celery_app = Celery(
    'broker_name',
)

celery_app.conf.broker = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL')
celery_app.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULTS_BACKEND')
celery_app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'queue_order_strategy': 'priority',
    'visibility_timeout': 86400,
    'max_retries': 1,
}

celery_app.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)

celery_app.conf.critical_queues = [Queue('critical', Exchange('critical'), routing_key='critical',
                                         queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 2})]

celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'Run Every 15 Minutes': {
        'task': 'broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15'),
        'options': {'queue': 'critical'}
    },
    'Run Every 1 Hour': {
        'task': 'broker.tasks.run_hourly',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='0', hour='*/1'),
        'options': {'queue': 'critical'}
    },
    'Run Every 1 Day': {
        'task': 'broker.tasks.run_daily',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='0', hour='0'),
        'options': {'queue': 'critical'}
    }
}
celery_app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'

celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(['broker.tasks'], force=True)


My broker.tasks.py file
import os

import psycopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from .celery import celery_app
from db.get_db import get_conn_cursor

load_dotenv("./.env")


@celery_app.task
def run_fifteen_minutes(bind = True,max_retries = 1 ,retry_backoff = True):
    conn, cur = get_conn_cursor()
    with open(os.environ.get('REFRESH_EVERY_15_MINUTES_PATH'), "r") as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        lines = [l for l in file_data.splitlines() if '--' not in l]
        for x in lines:
            try:
                cur.execute(query=x)
                conn.commit()
            except psycopg2.Error as e:
                print(f'Encountered psycopg2 error: {e}')
                conn.rollback()
    return


@celery_app.task
def run_hourly(bind = True,max_retries = 1 ,retry_backoff = True):
    conn, cur = get_conn_cursor()
    with open(os.environ.get('REFRESH_EVERY_1_HOUR_PATH'), "r") as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        lines = [l for l in file_data.splitlines() if '--' not in l]
        for x in lines:
            try:
                cur.execute(query=x)
                conn.commit()
            except psycopg2.Error as e:
                print(f'Encountered psycopg2 error: {e}')
                conn.rollback()
    return


@celery_app.task
def run_daily(bind = True,max_retries = 1 ,retry_backoff = True):
    conn, cur = get_conn_cursor()
    with open(os.environ.get('REFRESH_EVERY_1_DAY_PATH'), "r") as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        lines = [l for l in file_data.splitlines() if '--' not in l]
        for x in lines:
            try:
                cur.execute(query=x)
                conn.commit()
            except psycopg2.Error as e:
                print(f'Encountered psycopg2 error: {e}')
                conn.rollback()
    return


Can you show how you start celery service? In bash it looks something like celery multi start 3 (...)

@Greg0ry
celery -A broker.celery.celery_app worker -B --detach -E --loglevel=INFO --logfile logs/celery.log -Q critical --concurrency=1

As you can see from celery logs the job_ids are different, this means that this is not the same task. Maybe the problem is in how you declare periodic tasks. Try changing broker.tasks.run_fifteen_minutes  simply to tasks.run_fifteen_minutes

I have tested your code and it worked without issues for me. I don't see any duplicated tasks. Are you sure that you are not making double imports that might duplicate celery_app? Or could it be the issue with your AMPQ queue which has a lot of old non completed tasks?

Could you show me what broker settings you've used ?
I'm using a standard redis broker, default config and a postgresql backend.
